# iCloud sync files and core data

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, nsfilemanager, file-manager

In my app I save images in file manager and their metadata(image name,created date,notes and image path) in core data.
I want to know the best practice to sync these data using iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

If you save the images in the ubiquity container they will be synchronised across devices.  However you may need to store a relative pathname rather than an absolute pathname.

If you take a look at the the sample apps at the link below you will find the app uses iCloud to synchronise the Core Data database using transaction logs and it uses iCloud to synchronise the backup files the user makes.  So while this is not exactly what you want it would be pretty easy to modify the code for saving the backup files to iCloud to save your files to iCloud.

You do need to remember that iOS will not automatically download files from iCloud so you would have to do that from your App prior to trying to use them on the device.

http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/